# contact form PHP redirect is not working

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I im trying to redirect to my homepage after submitting a message on my contact form, the form sends the email but I get this message:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Abdo
    [company] => Mediabyrån A&B
    [email] => a.el-madhoun@hotmail.com
    [content] => Hejsan
    [contact_to] => info@web.se
)
```

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /customers/4/5/a/webelite.se/httpd.www/kontakt.php:3) in
>   /customers/4/5/a/webelite.se/httpd.www/kontakt.php on line 39

My contact form;

```
<form action="kontakt.php" method="post">
<p><input type="text" required="required" id="name" name="name" class="text_input" size="22"  />
<label for="name">Namn *</label></p>

<p><input type="text" required="required" id="company" name="company" class="text_input" size="22"  />
<label for="company">Företag *</label></p>

<p><input type="email" required="required" id="email" name="email" class="text_input"  size="22"  />
<label for="email">Epost *</label></p>

<p><textarea required="required" name="content" class="textarea" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>

<p><button type="submit" class="button white"><span>Skicka</span></button></p>
<input type="hidden" value="info@web.se" name="contact_to"/>
</form>
```

and this is my PHP:

```
<?php

echo $name = $_POST['name'];
echo $company = $_POST['company'];
echo $email =  $_POST['email'];
echo $content = $_POST['content'];

$mail_to = 'info@webelite.se';
$subject = 'Lilla form'.$name;

$body_message = 'From: '. $name . "\n"; 
$body_message .= 'company: '. $company . "\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '. $email ."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '. $content;

$headers = 'From: '. $mail_name . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $email ."\r\n";

$success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);

header('Location:mydomain');

?>
```

I also tried using if

```
($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=YOUR_PAGE_HERE.html\">";
```

This worked but I got a ugly half a second flash between hitting submit and being redirected.

All help is appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't output anything to the screen before redirecting.

Remove all your `echo`'es and `print_r`'s and you should be fine.

**EDIT:**

Also as @jhonraymos mentioned, be sure to use `header()` properly. Maybe you changed this to hide your actual page you're redirecting to. Either add a local file with correct path definitions or if redirecting to an other domain, you need to define the full url. See [Uniform resource locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) if in doubt.

**Another EDIT:**

I see you updated your question. Stop trying indian magic, such as

```
if ($success){
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=YOUR_PAGE_HERE.html\">";
```

Just accept the fact not to output **ANYTHING** to the screen before `headers()` and your soul is safe forever. This is not the place to mix http-meta in. PHP can do this just fine.

This might sound as a limitation first, but believe me, it isn't. It's a blessing.

Comment: So the headers goes first on my php and removing the echos?

Comment: The headers can actually stay where they are. Just don't ouput anything to the screen before calling `header()`

Answer (score 4):

this is error

```
print_r($_POST);

header('Location:mydomain');
```

You are printing something before the `header("location: mydomain.com")`

Answer (score 4):

Headers are used to communicate with your client's browser. They're like little commands that the browser will perform when received. When you output any data (text,numbers,whatever), you're client's browser will print that data. After that, the browser will no longer be interested in any headers you send.

The `header()` function is a function used to send custom headers. So when this function is called, headers are sent out to your client's browser.

Now you have a very brief understanding of what it is you're actually trying to do, you should be able to see where your problem lies.

You are outputting other data before sending those custom headers. This is what's triggering the error.

So this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

Should not be before this:

```
header('Location:mydomain');
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, you are not supposed to echo, print anything before `header`
try placing this at the top of your page:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

then at the bottom of the page place :

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: thank you Its working, you guys are the best, fast help and great advice for a noob... Thank you

Comment: Although this might work, I really recommend that you don't adapt this as a programming habit because it is a no, no and no.

Comment: @user1741191 Use ob_end_flush() at the end.

Comment: @user1741191 as budwiser suggested this is not a good programming approach

Answer (score 2):

What the 
`echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);`
is for ?

Your redirection may happen before any echo function is called, no ?

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);` is obviously there to debug the data in `$_POST`. The OP just didn't realize this prevents modifying headers.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common problem in php. some ways to sort out:

1. use  on top of the page.
2. check if you accidentally add some white spaces before the php open tag or after the php closed tag.
3. if still not solve, use java-script window.location instead of header.

Hope it help.
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You get this warning because you output to the screen your variables' values and redirecting with `header` after that.

Headers **cannot** be sent **after** your print something (`echo` , `print_r` ...).
In order to fix it , follow the next code:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; //no echo 
$company = $_POST['company'];//no echo 
$email =  $_POST['email'];//no echo 
$content = $_POST['content'];//no echo 




$mail_to = 'info@webelite.se';
$subject = 'Lilla form'.$name;



$body_message = 'From: '. $name . "\n"; 
$body_message .= 'company: '. $company . "\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '. $email ."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '. $content;



$headers = 'From: '. $mail_name . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $email ."\r\n";



$success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);



//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($_POST);
```