# Simple PHP form still not working

Tags: php, html, forms

Im uploading my website at the moment. However, I do not get my PHP code to work. I do have an mail server set up with the correct e-mail address. But when I use the script and press the button to send the form it gives me a blank page and no e-mail showing in my mailbox.

Could someone help me please ?

Find below my coding:

```
        <div id="thirdColumn">
            <div id="contactOns">

                <form action="send.php" method="post" class="form">  

                    <p class="name">  
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="NAAM" />  
                    </p>  

                    <p class="email">  
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />   
                    </p>  

                    <p class="text">  
                        <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>  
                    </p>  

                    <p class="submit">  
                        <input type="submit" id="sent" value="VERSTUUR" />  
                    </p>  

                </form>  

            </div> <!-- End contactOns -->
        </div> <!-- End thirdColumn -->
```

And here my PHP:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mail_to = 'info@dereebokgrandcafe.nl';
  $subject = 'Bericht van een bezoeker '.$name;

  $body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
  $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
  $body_message .= 'Message: '.$message;

  $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually tries to send the mail?

Comment: where is mail() function ?

Comment: where is your mail() ?  Add this at end `$success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);`  and take a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884612/contact-form-php-redirect-is-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mail_to = 'info@dereebokgrandcafe.nl';
  $subject = 'Bericht van een bezoeker '.$name;

  $body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
  $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
  $body_message .= 'Message: '.$message;

  $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

  mail($mail_to,$subject,$body_message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately! You are missing `mail function`.

```
  mail($mail_to,$subject,$body_message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the end of your script to test sending mail , and send.

```
if(mail(mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) echo 'Mail sent '; else echo 'problem !';
```